# SAS proc to display table with two variables as row and one variable as column

Tags: sas, analysis, sas-studio

I have a dataset as follows:

ID |----A---|-----B--|  TIME

1--|----1---|   ----0---|   q1

2--|----0---|   ----1---|   q2

3--|----0---|   ----0---|   q3

4--|----1---|   ----1---|   q4

where 1 means present and 0 means not present

How can I write proc statement to output a frequency table as follows:

```
          TIME

   Q1             Q2            Q3                   Q4    TOTAL
```

A

0 ---10---------------20---------------5-------------------3

1----5----------------35---------------2--------------------1

B

0-------1------------2-------------------32-------------------2

1------6--------------3-------------------2-------------------3

Thanks

Comment: welcome :-) I'm having a hard time understanding the shape of your posted sample data. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes sorry trying to figure out how to format the table. Is that better

Comment: Somewhat better ;-) Question: Where do the values 10, 20, 5 ... come from in your desired table?

Comment: The number of records in A or B with 1s and 0s

Comment: Is the output of PROC FREQ not good enough?  Did you try PROC TABULATE?

Comment: So im not too sure how to do proc freq with the 3 columns, one way i've done it is making two seperate proc freq tables one for tables A TIME and one for B TIME. But wondering is there a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

PROC TABULATE is better here as you have a bit more control over the table structure especially with multiple variables.

Something like this - untested because your data is in an unusable form.

```
proc tabulate data=have;
class a b time;

table a b, (time all='Total');
run;
```